# Length of $error in ngMessages module of AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, count, ng-messages

Here is the basic way to use ngMessages module. `myForm.myName.$error` return list of error. I want to get number of errors. I have tried `{{myForm.myName.$error | json}}.length` and `myForm.myName.$error.length`.

```
<form name="myForm">
  <label>
    Enter your name:
    <input type="text"
           name="myName"
           ng-model="name"
           ng-minlength="5"
           ng-maxlength="20"
           required />
  </label>
  <pre>myForm.myName.$error = {{ myForm.myName.$error | json }}</pre>

  <div ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
    <div ng-message-default>This field has an input error</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you missed it in the [documentation for the ngMessages module.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages#message-order)

> By default, `ngMessages` will only display one message for a particular key/value collection at any time.

This means `myForm.myName.$error` can only ever have a maximum of one property.

If you want to support the display of multiple messages, apply the `ng-messages-multiple` attribute alongside the `ng-messages` directive. With this applied, you can retrieve the number of active errors by creating a helper function.

```
function getErrorCount() {
    return Object.keys(myForm.myName.$error).length;
}
```

[Here's a demonstration of the suggestion above.](http://plnkr.co/edit/jgeug2?p=preview)